# Apache Airflow - Authentication issues using RBAC

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have a bit of an issue

Airflow     **1.10.10**

Python      **3.7**

OS          **redhat enterprise**

Environment **GCP w/ Compute Instances**

Nginx       **Compute Instance**

We are using (multiple) Airflow and going through an NGINX reverse proxy (All on Google Cloud Platform)

We have a main domain (example.com) which re-directs to multiple locations based on their path.
We set the locations to be dynamic based on variables. Lets call it VarA and VarB. This points to the individual instances that are running Airflow.
The Postgres DB is different per instance per  webserver deployment.

```
Snippet of Nginx Conf
...

server_name example.com

location ~/airflow-<varA>-<varB>/.*
  proxy_pass http://varA.example-instance.our-org.com/airflow-varB
```

The rest of the location block i've configured from here:

https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/run-behind-proxy.html

We have the current settings in airflow.cfg enabled:

```
rbac = True
fernet_key = <the same for every image we build>
sercret_key = temporary_key (default)
base_url = <machine_dns_name:8080>
```

When our CI builds and deploys Airflow, we can navigate to each airflow instance correctly. The problem is:

Once we authenticate with 1 instance by navigating to the URL

E.G

https://example.com/airflow-varA-varB`

We can browse to ALL other airflow instances we have spawned without authenticating (Username and Passwords are ALL different on every instance)

When we build the image, we use `airflow create_user` to create the first user on the DB.

I have tried adding the

- Secure cookie option
- SameSite Cookie
- the enable_proxy_fix

All doesn't work.

One of the things that kind of worked was that I changed the `secret_key` to something we set manually rather than the`os.urandom(16)` as by the source code, and that allowed us to log in differently to each instance

HOWEVER

When we loaded another instance in the URL, and clicked refresh or logged into another instance, it logged the first logged-in instance off.

**UPDATE:**

I know its linked the to USER_ID of the RBAC user in `ab_user` table  (As the user we create is always User 1)

How i know this is because if i altered the USERID in the PG database, change the `ab_user_roles` to reflect the new user ID in the `ab_user` table and make the user ID a random integer, It works, & i can log into once instance and the other instance if i load it in the URL , asks me to log in.

Airflow isn't sending any cookies to associate the user ID so how is it working? Is it Gunicorn or Flask that's the issue?

I don’t want to alter the USERID when we create a user I Airflow because its not as secure.
Any help is appreciate